# Css code quality?

Tags: css

I'm not a css expert so please help me figuring this out.    Would you consider this as good css code?

Please point any issues if you believe this is not what you would exactly consider as good code.

```
                               html { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 70%;  }
  body {  margin:0px; padding:0px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  }
 { font-size:14px;}
 #wrap { width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#FFFFFF; padding: 0;}

  #header {
  padding: 10px;

  height:251px;
  }

  #menu { width:100%; height:2.2em; margin-top:1%;  background:#80b2e4; border-      radius:10px; -moz-border-radius:10px; -webkit-moz-border-radius:10px;}
 .top_menu_left {float:left; width:86%;height:35px; margin-left:3%;}
 .top_menu_left li a    { color:#fff !important; }
 .top_menu_left li a:hover  { color:#336699 !important; }

 .top_menu_right {float:right; width:17%;;height:1.2em;}
 li{list-style:none; float:left;  color:#74677E;font-size:70%;font-   weight:bold;font-     family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:left; padding:0  5px;  -top:9px;  color:#fff;}

.top_menu_left li {padding-right:1%; color:#fff;}
.top_menu_right li {padding-right:5%; color:#fff;}

#searchbar { width:100%; height:auto;margin-top:8%;}

#top_search {width:100%; height:auto;}
#bottom_search {width:89%; height:auto;padding-left:10.5%;font-size:75%;}

.sarch_box { width:10%; height:auto; float:left; margin-left:1%;font-size:75%;}

.box_1 { width:20%; height:auto; float:left;font-size:85%;}
.box_1 input { width:80%; height:1.2em;font-size:85%;}
.box_1 select { width:70%; height:1.5em;font-size:85%;}

.box_2 {width:2%; height:auto; float:left;}

#content { width:87%; height:auto; margin-left:11%; margin-top:0; }
#left_content { width:7%; height:auto; float:left; }
#left_searchbar_title {width:95%;height:2%;padding-top:1%;padding-  bottom:1%;padding-     left:5%;background-color:#A5D959;font-family:Arial, Helvetica,   sans-serif;font-size:75%;}
#left_sidebar_content{width:100%;height:2%;background-color:#EFFFD8;font-  family:Arial,   Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:75%;}

 #main_content { width:59%; height:auto;float:left;  }
.main_content_header  {margin-left:2%;color:black;font-size:100%;font- family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:bold;margin-bottom:5%;}

.content_header {width:70%; height:auto; margin-left:3%;}

 /*.left_1 {margin-left:2%;width:.05em; height:100px;background- image:url(images/verticalbar.gif);background-repeat:repeat-y;float:left;padding-left:2px;    }*/
 .left_1 {margin-left:2%;width:.05em; height:100px;background-image:none;background-   repeat:repeat-y;float:left;padding-left:2px; }
/*.left_6 { width:.05em;height:100px;background-   image:url(images/verticalbar.gif);background-repeat:repeat-y;float:left; }*/
.left_6 { width:.05em;height:100px;background-image:none;background-repeat:repeat-   y;float:left; }

.left_content_middle    {width:95%;float:left;font-size:80%;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background:white; border:1px solid #c6c6c6;border-radius:10px; webkit-border-radius:10px; -moz-border-radius:10px}

.content_title {padding:2%; text-align:center; color:black; <!--#336699;-->font-  weight:bold;font-size:100%;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

.content_line{size:2px; width:95%; background-image:url(images/horizotal-line.gif);}

.left_2 { margin-left:3%; width:21.5%; height:auto; float:left; }
.left_3 { width:23.5%;height:auto;float:left;}
.left_4 { width:23.5%;height:auto;float:left;}
.left_5 { width:23.5%;height:auto;float:left;}


  #right_content { width:20%;height:auto;background-color:white;float:left;margin-   left:1%;padding:10px; border:1px solid #c6c6c6; border-radius:10px; webkit-border-   radius:10px; -moz-border-radius:10px}
 .right_top { width:100%; height:auto; color:white; font-size:100%; color:#336699;}

 .Left_portion { width:45%; height:auto; float:left;padding-left:8%;}

 .right_portion { width:45%; height:auto; float:left;}

 .right_content_title {color:#BB532E;font-weight:bold;font-size:70%;font-family:Arial,  Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom:4%;padding-top:5%; }
 .right_content_body {color:#5E6472;font-size:70%;font-weight:bold;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-bottom:3%;}



  .menu_bar { width:10%; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:red; float:left; font-size:50%;}

  .gap {width:35%;}

   #footer   {height:40px;width:100%;margin:auto;text-align:center;text-  align:center;margin-top:2%;background:url('images/footer_bg.png') repeat-x;    line-height:40px; color:white;}
  .footer_menu {
   color: white;
   float: right;
   height: 1.2em;
   -left: 3%;
   width: 70%;
   }
     .footer_menu li {
     color: white;
     padding-right: 1%;
  }
    .footer_menu li a   { color:#fff; text-decoration:none;}
    .footer_menu li a:hover { text-decoration:underline}
    .footer_menu2 {
    background: url("images/footer_bg2.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: grey;
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: 21px;
    width: 100%;
    }
   .footer_menu strong  { font-weight:lighter; color:#666}
```

Comment: Whats your markup those goes with this CSS?

Comment: Looks pretty good to me, whole point of using a css file is to reduce redundancy, and you don't seem to have much.  Maybe the .Left_i from 3-5, but other than that it looks pretty good.  Really depends on what you are trying to get out of it.

Comment: What's the context?  It looks like everything is relatively sized so the page will look different when the browser window is a different resolution.  Can we see the HTML it's associated with?  Also, is there a specific question you have about the css? "Good" and "bad" are kind of arbitrary right now

Comment: Others will add more specifics, but as with all code, grouping and commenting CSS will greatly aid in maintainability.

Comment: There is **a lot of redundancy** and overspecification in your stylesheet. Too many `!important` declarations, too many repeated selectors and properties... the one thing that you don't have enough of is indentation.

Answer (score 5):

```
html { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 70%;  }
body {  margin:0px; padding:0px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  }
```

There's no need to specify the unit (px) if the value is 0

```
{ font-size:14px;}
```

This isn't styling anything

```
#wrap { width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#FFFFFF; padding: 0;}
```

Assuming #wrap is a div or other block level element it's unnecesarry to give it a width of 100% as all block elements *are* 100% wide by default. Padding is also 0 by default in almost all elements.

```
#header {
padding: 10px;

height:251px;
}
```

You should never give elements (except images/canvases) a height because if the user increases the font-size the element should adjust to the new size of the content.

```
#menu { width:100%; height:2.2em; margin-top:1%;  background:#80b2e4; border-      radius:10px; -moz-border-radius:10px; -webkit-moz-border-radius:10px;}
```

Again, no need to set the width and why would you suddenly use em for the height? It's common to also put the -browser-specific properties *before* the "real" ones.

```
.top_menu_left {float:left; width:86%;height:35px; margin-left:3%;}
.top_menu_left li a    { color:#fff !important; }
.top_menu_left li a:hover  { color:#336699 !important; }
```

Having something like "left" (or right, bold, red, etc) as a class name is not separating the content from the presentation. Also you should try to avoid using !important as it often leads to more use of !important and hard to find bugs.

```
.top_menu_right {float:right; width:17%;;height:1.2em;}
```

Again the class name is design related.

```
li{list-style:none; float:left;  color:#74677E;font-size:70%;font-   weight:bold;font-     family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:left; padding:0  5px;  -top:9px;  color:#fff;}
```

Do you *really* want all your li:s in your entire document to have this styling? There's also syntax errors (like -top).

```
.top_menu_left li {padding-right:1%; color:#fff;}
.top_menu_right li {padding-right:5%; color:#fff;}
```

Again the class name - also, this should probably be next to the other styling of the same element.

```
#searchbar { width:100%; height:auto;margin-top:8%;}
```

No need to set width *or* height here as you set them to default values. Also - why would you use an #id here but a .class for almost everything else?

I'll stop quoting code here as the rest contains pretty much the same faults.

**A few things I would improve:**

- Don't use design related class or ID-names like left and right.
- Don't use !important - instead plan your code in a way that doesn't require it.
- Don't use percentages for everything.
- Structure your CSS in a way that makes a little more sense. You don't have to keep it all in one file (in fact, you probably shouldn't (but you should only *serve* one file to the browser though)). This tip would probably require an entire book but a few things to get you started:

  - Start with basic element selectors (like h1, p, a, ul etc) - the generic styling that will be default for everything on your page.
  - Next do your layout - right/left columns and other areas for your "modules".
  - Last style your modules - the #searchbar should have this bg, #recent-comments links should be red, the #footer's ul shouldn't have any bullets etc.

Also, since everything else in HTML uses dash-separation I use that for my class and ID names as well.

Comment: !important is very necessary when doing adaptive (or reactive) design.  Dumb example: `body article br {display: none}` would mean there's no actual break when I use a `<br>` tag in within an `<article>` tag. But, lets say that I insert the `<br>` to cause a break on screen sizes less than 320px `@media screen and (max-width: 320px){ body article br {display: block !important;}}` without the `!important` that style will not display properly. `!important` exists for some very good reasons and should be used when appropriate since there are times when you can't "html around" it.

Comment: Or you could just put that styling _after_ the first.

Comment: I still don't see why using !important is "bad" and why it should be avoided.  ergo http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: Well, in the article you link to it's explained why it's "bad" in the first paragraph. I agree that it can be useful _sometimes_ but _very_ rarely. I've used it to to style .todo elements to always have a red dotted border. But as the name suggests the .todo class is very temporary and never makes it to the live site.

Comment: I agree that !important should only be used when absolutely necessary. It's often used in a lazy fashion, which causes hell for developers that come across this later.

Comment: Powerful code review

Answer (score 1):

I don't beleave it is "good" CSS code because:

- It is inconsistant (white space, multi/single line, etc)
- There are obvious syntax errors
- There is a lot of repetition
- It is mostly percent based sizes which will break in a lot of cases
- There is rules that will be used by default anyway, hence don't need to be specified
- There is too much use of the `!important` keyword